# Xcode IOS5 retrieve filenames

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I wish to retrieve all filenames from the root directory with the extension *.gs and store them in an array.

I tried using directoryContentsAtPath.. but it says that this method has been deprecated in ios5. Do you know any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NSFileManager`'s:

```
– contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error:
```

(See [Apple's documentation on NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).)

You will end up with something like:

```
NSString *path = @"your/path";
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

If you feel you don't need to check for a potential error, you may pass `nil` for the `error` argument. However, I would recommend that you check whether an error occurred and display an appropriate error message in that case. You could do it like so:

```
if (error) {
    // display some error message here
} else {
    // process filenames returned by NSFileManager
}
```